# How to create Spring Bean (DataSource) with parameter?

Tags: java, spring

Colleagues, i am new in Spring 4. 
I have a class which call procedure:

```
public class ProductDAOImpl implements ProductDAO  {

  public Product getProductUsingProc(int PassID, int Amount) {


        SqlParameterSource sqlParameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("PassID", PassID).addValue("Amount", Amount);
         WebServiceConfig wsc = new WebServiceConfig();

        DataSource dataSource = wsc.DataSource("DB1"); 
        SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("PRODUCT_CREATE");

        Map<String, Object> result = simpleJdbcCall.execute(sqlParameterSource);

        Product product = new Product();

        product.setPassID(PassID); 
        product.setAmount(Amount);
        product.setReturnValue( (int) result.get("ReturnValue") );
        product.setProductID((int) result.get("ProductID"));

        return product;
    }
```

I need to use dataSource with different input arguments.

My bean in WebServiceConfig (wsc) look like:

```
@Bean
        public BasicDataSource DataSource(String source) {
             /*some code using input parameter*/

            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:....");
            dataSource.setUsername("user");
            dataSource.setPassword("pass");
            dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
            dataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
            dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
            dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(false);
            dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
            dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
            return dataSource;
        }
```

But when run program i receive next stack trace:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)


ERROR: [oct-26 16:46:44,337] springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined in class path resource [com/mayacomp/service/app/WebServiceConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang. String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for  this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Depende ncy annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBean Factory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav a:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.mayacomp.service.app.WsApplication.main(WsApplication.java:12) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: e xpected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.jav a:1301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 18 more Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'DataSource' defined i n class path resource [com/mayacomp/service/app/WebServiceConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifie s as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefiniti onException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate f or this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:749)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:464)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBean Factory.java:1119)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.jav a:1014)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)

        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:303)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:299)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:755)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:686)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:320)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:957)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:946)
        at com.mayacomp.service.app.WsApplication.main(WsApplication.java:12) Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: e xpected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.jav a:1301)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1047)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:942)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:813)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
        ... 18 more
```

When i use bean without "String source" it works fine?

**UPDATE**

I solved problem by using separate bean for every datasource:

```
@Bean
    @Primary
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.primary")
        public BasicDataSource DataSource() {
            BasicDataSource dataSource = new BasicDataSource();
            dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://");
            dataSource.setUsername("user");
            dataSource.setPassword("pass");
            dataSource.setMaxIdle(10);
            dataSource.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
            dataSource.setValidationQuery("select 1");
            dataSource.setTestOnBorrow(false);
            dataSource.setTestWhileIdle(true);
            dataSource.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
            return dataSource;
        }

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public BasicDataSource DataSource1() {
        BasicDataSource DataSource1 = new BasicDataSource();
        DataSource1.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        DataSource1.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://");
        DataSource1.setUsername("user");
        DataSource1.setPassword("pass");
        DataSource1.setMaxIdle(10);
        DataSource1.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
        DataSource1.setValidationQuery("select 1");
        DataSource1.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        DataSource1.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        DataSource1.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
        return DataSource1;
    }


    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix="datasource.secondary")
    public BasicDataSource DataSource2() {
        BasicDataSource DataSource2 = new BasicDataSource();
        DataSource2.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        DataSource2.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://");
        DataSource2.setUsername("user");
        DataSource2.setPassword("pass");
        DataSource2.setMaxIdle(10);
        DataSource2.setMaxWaitMillis(10000);
        DataSource2.setValidationQuery("select 1");
        DataSource2.setTestOnBorrow(false);
        DataSource2.setTestWhileIdle(true);
        DataSource2.setDefaultAutoCommit(true);
        return DataSource2;
    }
```

Comment: What does that `source` represent... Why is it a `String`

Comment: Source is a name of database, I will add switch instead of /*some code using input parameter*/ and will return specified dataSource to get data from DB.

Comment: Looks like you are reinventing a wheel in a very complex way. Hibernate already has out-of-the-box multi tenancy support and another one is documented [here](https://mdeinum.wordpress.com/2007/01/05/one-application-per-client-database/). That way you don't need to mess around with datasources. (Maybe I should update it to show java-config instead of xml config).

Comment: I my case I can not use Hibernate, I use Spring SimpleJdbcCall. Like  SimpleJdbcCall simpleJdbcCall = new SimpleJdbcCall(dataSource).withProcedureName("PR_CREATE"); And I would like to determine datasource use code like DataSource dataSource = SpringConfigFile.DataSource("TEST_DB");

Comment: No you don't want that as you don't want to create a `SimpleJdbcCall` each time you need. It construct a `JdbcTemplate` which is a quite heavy operation. You want to do things like that transparantly, hence the switching of the datasource. The solution I pointed you to works with about 75 different datasources in production (for about 10 years now) it works regardless of the technology used (and works with basically every bean you want).

Answer (score 3):

When you pass parameters in methods annotated with @Bean every parameter is resolved by the spring container, in your specific case spring can'f find a bean of type string to satisfy the dependency because you haven't set up any (and you shouldn't have! :)).

If you want to inject some parameters, spring provides you with the @Value annotation (this is one of few different ways spring can be helpful to inject properties btw), eg:

```
public BasicDataSource DataSource(@Value("${your.property.name}") String source)
```

You'll need to define the property your.property.name inside the application.properties file inside your resource folder like this

your.property.name=my value

n.b.

you can use @PropertySource in your context configuration file to import properties from wherever you prefer http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/PropertySource.html (I've been so spoiled by spring boot that I forgot if spring automatically loads the properties on its own :D)

Comment: Emanuele Ivaldi, thank you fro response. I add class which describes how i use dataSource. Please, look. May be it helps to understand my problem: i want to get datasourse based on input parameter.

Comment: You are welcome, you can define as many datasource as you want  in your context (all of them can load the properties like I've shown on my response), then have some sort of provider to get them at runtime based on a parameter, if you really want to do that.

Comment: You mean that i should create some different datasources (beans) with different names and urls/users/pass?

Comment: That really depends on your application, but it's certainly a possibile solution.

Comment: I will try to add some new beans like DataSourceDB1, DataSourceDB2 in my spring config file. It will be a little code repeating, but if it will work i will be glad. Thank you.

Comment: Yup that's a common practice btw.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a @PropertySource("yourFile.properties") on your configuration and get property through environment like this :

```
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource("yourFile.properties")
    public class YourConfiguration{

        @Autowired
        Environment env

        @Bean
        public BasicDataSource DataSource() {
         String source = env.getProperty("source");
         //your code below
        }
     }
```

Hope this help

Comment: I need to get property in from file depends on input Source parameter. If  Source = "DB1" then i need to get url,user, pass for prod DB1, if Source = "DB2" then i need to get url,user, pass for prod DB2.

Comment: You could also have a look on @Profile which let you define profile for your application (one for DB1, one for DB2 for example). If you only need value answer of Emanuele Ivaldi will work.

Comment: @Value can be used together with profiles, profiles can be used to load different properties file, there's a really nice opionionated way of doing exactly that in spring boot